# Angular project keeps showing old component html template in browser after replacing it

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-library, angular-cache

I am currently developing Angular libraries for reuse across different angular projects in our software department. One library is a login form. I published it to npm and installed and imported it in another angular project so I can replace the old login form with the new one.

**Problem is:** Although there is nowhere any reference at all to the old login-form component, I still keep seeing the old login form in the browser. The typescript file of the login form however seems to be replaced/updated as expected (E.g. validation messages are different now). It's like the frontend of the old login form is cached somewhere and I can't get rid of it. I already tried installing a new browser as well as deleting the cache of the browser and of Angular with "ng cache clean". It's becoming so weird that if I search for innertext (e.g. "Load Models") from the old login form in my VS Code, I get no results (as expected because I got rid of the login-form template). But I still keep seeing it in the browser!

Is there anything I might be missing?

[Old login form - what I am seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4gyZ.png)   [New login form - what I should be seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02LDE.png)

Comment: In my experience such odd issues normally mean I've missed the obvious & am looking too deep...  How are you running your app; is it hosted somewhere, or is this running it on your dev machine?  If on your dev machine, are you sure you're accessing the current version (e.g. sometimes the port number used for hosting a runtime http server changes each run and you find you're looking at the wrong instance by not using the new port number in your test URI).

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] Seems like NPM has its own cache as well. Deleting "node_modules" and "package.json" and then running "npm install" solved my issue.